# Bad SQLite query performance with outer joins

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database as part of an iOS app which works fine for the most part but certain small changes to a query can result in it taking 1000x longer to complete. Here's the 2 tables I have involved:

```
create table "journey_item" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"position" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"last_update" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"rank" DOUBLE PRECISION NOT NULL,
"skipped" BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
"item_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"journey_id" INTEGER NOT NULL);

create table "content_items" ("id" SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"full_id" VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
"title" VARCHAR(508),
"timestamp" BIGINT NOT NULL,
"item_size" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"http_link" VARCHAR(254),
"local_url" VARCHAR(254),
"creator_id" INTEGER NOT NULL,
"from_id" INTEGER,"location_id" INTEGER);
```

Tables have indexes on primary and foreign keys.

And here are 2 queries which give a good example of my problem

```
SELECT * FROM content_items ci 
INNER JOIN journey_item ji ON ji.item_id = ci.id WHERE ji.journey_id = 1

SELECT * FROM content_items ci 
LEFT OUTER JOIN journey_item ji ON ji.item_id = ci.id WHERE ji.journey_id = 1
```

The first query takes 167 ms to complete while the second takes 3.5 minutes and I don't know why the outer join would make such a huge difference.

Edit:
Without the WHERE part the second query only takes 267 ms

Comment: Use [EXPLAIN](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_explain.html) to obtain the execution plan

Comment: @cha I looked at EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN. The second has a SCAN of content_items followed by a SEARCH of journey_item which is what I would expect. I'm not really sure how to read the results from EXPLAIN. There are a few extra NE opcodes but I don't know why these would change the performance so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two queries should have the same result set (the `where` clause turns the `left join` into an inner join)`.  However, SQLite probably doesn't recognize this.

If you have an index on `journey_item(journey_id, item_id)`, then this would be used for the `inner join` version.  However, the second version is probably scanning the first table for the join.  An index on `journey_item(item_id)` would help, but probably still not match the performance of the first query.

Comment: I had individual indexes on all my id and foreign key columns but I don't have any multi column indexes. I just added journey_item(journey_id, item_id) which seemed to fix the problem (but I need to do some more testing). Do I essentially need multi column indexes anywhere that I'm going to use both in a query?

Comment: @skorulis . . . An index on `journet_item(journey_id)` would also be a big help for the first query.